# Trigger Jenkins Build with "Poll SCM" AND "Build after other projects are built"

Tags: jenkins

I'd like to trigger the nightly cq build ONLY if last commit build was successful.

Currently I have the cq build being triggered with a scm poll at midnight, but I would like to include the additional condition that another build (the last commit build) was successful. Because it makes no sense letting the slow cq build run just to inevitably fail.

The build triggers section of a build have multiple ways of triggering a build including when another build is finished, but as far as I can tell these triggers happen if any one of them is selected I want to effectively AND the "Build after other projects are built" and "Poll SCM" conditions together.

I've looked at https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin 
but that's about putting conditions on a build step, not conditionally triggering the build as a whole.
and
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin
but that's about launching another build from another.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Regards,
Phil.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the **[Build Result Trigger](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/BuildResultTrigger+Plugin)** plugin